# How does one specify a forward reference in Erlang?

Tags: recursion, erlang, forward-declaration

I have been plaing around with Erlang, and decided to try to make a directory lister.  After hacking some code together I hit as road block, as the second commented line shows an error message.  Literally it can't see the iterate function.   I've done a bit of research here and on google.  I have tried exporting the functions as well.   **There is something here that I am not thinking about correctly.   Can someone point me in the correct direction?**

```
-module(iterate_dir).

% exporting iterate/1 does not make it visible.
-export([start/0, iterate/1, show_files/2]).

show_files([], _) ->
    ok;

show_files([Head|Tail], Path) ->
    FullPath = [Path] ++ [Head],
    case filelib:is_dir(FullPath) of
                                                    % function iteratate/1 undefined
        true -> io:format("Dir  ~s\n", [FullPath]), iteratate(FullPath);
        false-> io:format("File ~s\n", [FullPath])
    end,
    show_files(Tail, Path).


iterate(Directory) ->
    case file:list_dir(Directory) of
        {ok,    Files}   -> show_files(Files, Directory);
        {error, Reason}  -> io:format("Error ~s~n", [Reason])
    end.

start() ->
    io:format("Running~n"),
    iterate("c:\\"),
    io:format("Complete~n").
```

Comment: A typo. "iteratate" =/= "iterate"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is called "iterate", you are calling it as "iteratate"
notice the extra "at" in the middle at the call site (and comment)

Comment: Ya.  Bed time is in order.   Thank you David.